# How can I play two simultaneous TextToSpeech utterances in Android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am trying to play two simultaneous TextToSpeech utterances in Android (for research purposes), but I am not being able to do that. I know that it relies on a Queue and that it can speak (with the TextToSpeech.speak method) the text immediately or add it to the queue (with TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH and TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD).

I have tried by creating two TTS instances as shown below:

```
public Reader(Context c){

    ttobj=new TextToSpeech(c,
            new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                        ttobj.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
                    }
                }
            });

    ttobj2=new TextToSpeech(c,
            new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInit(int status) {
                    if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR){
                        ttobj.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
                    }
                }
            });

}
```

And I've also tried to run the secondary voice in a different thread, and to change the Audio Stream of that voice (to AudioManager.STREAM_RING), since the other one is on AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC. The thread code is:

```
Thread thread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        HashMap<String, String> myHashSecond = new HashMap();
        myHashSecond.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM,
                String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_RING));
        ttobj2.speak("Let me speak at the same time!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHashSecond);
    }
};
```

I am not being successful, since all my attempts interrupt or wait for the first utterance to end. Any ideas on how to enable such behavior?
Moreover, I prefer not having to save it to a file, but play it directly from the TTS.